# ALTER TABLE on a EXISTS condition with MySQL

Tags: mysql

### Context

I have an old database with relationships based on a string (person name), not the id. For instance, a `person` has many `comments` join by the column `person_name` on the `comments` table.

I would like to fix this by changing the column `person_name` into `person_id`.

### Create the new relationship

It consists of creating the new `person_id` column on `comments` and update the value:

```
UPDATE comments SET 
    person_id = (SELECT id FROM people WHERE LOWER(person_name) = name);
```

### Drop the old column

I cannot just drop `person_name` and update the foreign keys. I need to ensure all comments are properly linked to their authors. By simply selecting all the comments that have a `person_name` but an empty `person_id`, I can raise the red flag, because this migration will be applied automatically on many tables.

```
SELECT 1 FROM comments WHERE person_id IS NULL AND person_name IS NOT NULL
```

Notice that some comments are anonymous, so `person_name` could be `NULL`.

### Do the migration

To do this atomically I could do:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM comments WHERE person_id IS NULL AND person_name IS NOT NULL) 
THEN
    ALTER TABLE comments
    DROP COLUMN person_name;
END IF;
```

Unfortunately this seems to only work with MSSQL, not MySQL

What alternative can I use?

Comment: You are trying to execute SQL Server (MSSQL) syntax on MySQL.. MySQL does not support flowcontrol like that in plain queries what you can do is rewrite it to a stored procedure where MySQL does support flowcontrol..

Comment: I removed mine answer because of the comment "In your transaction you don't have a condition. How do you ensure the SELECT from the UPDATE has matched a row?. You could have an old_id not null and a new_id null." .. With other words the `ALTER ... DROP ...` can only happen when `new_id IS NULL AND old_id IS NOT NULL` is true for the complete table?

Comment: .... Your question is really not that clear.. i suggest you into providing example data and expected results.  To provide those i advice to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @RaymondNijland I haved edited my question to be more specific.